# Transform effect issue, the effect is showing behind

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

I was trying to learn how to do [this](https://i.postimg.cc/BbgxH6Mk/asd1.jpg) in Illustrator.

But instead I'm getting [this](https://i.postimg.cc/V6PMhMh2/IMG20220322083203.jpg).

I don't know how to make the transformation effect in front so it stays visible when I color the square. Pretty sure it is a dumb thing, but I can't see it.

Thx for the attention.

Comment: Your first image likely has a rectangle in the background with the gradient fill and then on top of that is the twisty squares with just a black stroke and no color fill. Are you also having trouble containing the rectangle twirl inside the rectangle shape or is that ammonite shape what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a small square, black stroke, white fill.

Then apply the transform with settings shown below.

[image]Click to see larger

Add a radial gradient

[image]

Use a square as a clipping mask

[image]

Another way you could colour it, just leave the square with a white fill, then draw a larger square on top with a radial fill, and in the appearance panel set the Opacity Blend mode to Multiply

[image]